# How to close publishing application.wadl?

Tags: java, jersey, wadl

I have a Jersey REST application. It exposes its wadl under /application.wadl. How can I close it to outside or how can I change its URL from /application.wadl?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can only disable it for the whole application (it's not possible to expose it on a different path). Set property

```
jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl
```

to `true`. You can find more about this property in javadoc: [ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE).